# Javascript FB.api - undefined error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use JS interface for facebook api and it is my first application for it.
Here is a snippet:

HTML:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">facebook_init();</script>
```

JS:

```
function facebook_init() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<MY APP ID IS HERE>',
      channelUrl : '/media/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
              alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
            });
}
```

channel.html:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js"></script>
```

I have 'Your name is undefined' when I load this page.
But this code

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'MSG',
      title: 'TITLE'});
```

works as expected.
Could you please help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log your `response` variable via `console.log(response)` [you'll see what's wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/rpPAG/):
You'll get an error object with this message:

```
"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
```

So if you want to get information about the current user you have to send also an Access Token. To get more information about this check the [Facebook JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the user has logged into Facebook and authorized your app, before you call FB.api('/me', ...).

Here's the general information: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Answer (score 0):

To overcome with `Undefined` problem use the following code:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : '<APP ID>',                        
  status     : true,                                 
  xfbml      : true                                 
});

// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
alert("connected");
connecter=true;
FB.api('/me', function(user) {
alert(user.name);
alert(user.first_name);
alert(user.last_name);
alert(user.email);
});

  } 
 });
```